# Skipping until parser match using pidgin

Tags: c#, parsing, parser-combinators

I try to find the numbers of apples and oranges in different strings using Pidgin, but i cant seem to skip over variable lengths of text, I want to find the numbers 1,2,3,4 in the following:

```
List<string> testStrings = new List<string> {
                "12 blerg",
                "1 apples",
                "  2 apples ignore_this",
                "3 oranges ignore_this",
                "this 5 6 should be ignored but fails 4 apples ignore_this"};
```

I can get 1,2,3, to work, i.e. skip whitespace and ignore text after keywords, I have tried skipUntil but can't get it to work, the string "this 5 6 should be ignored but fails 4 apples ignore_this" should return the number 4 but is skipped completely.

The code is in this (non-working) fiddle, so you need to run it locally :/

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jEppA8

edit: full listing below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Pidgin;
using static Pidgin.Parser;
using static Pidgin.Parser<char>;

public class Program
{ 

        public static void Main()
        {
            Parser<char, string> multiThings = OneOf(
                    String("apples"),
                    String("oranges")
                    );

            Parser<char, string> amountOfThings = Digit.ManyString().Between(Whitespaces, Whitespaces);
            Parser<char, string> amountOfThingsFollowedBy = amountOfThings.Before(Whitespaces.Before(multiThings));
            Parser<char, string> simpleSkipBefore = amountOfThings.Before(Any.SkipUntil(amountOfThings));
            Parser<char, string> simpleSkipAfter = Any.SkipUntil(amountOfThings).Then(amountOfThingsFollowedBy);

            Parser<char, string> amountOfThingsAnyWhere = OneOf(
            amountOfThingsFollowedBy,
            simpleSkipBefore,
            simpleSkipAfter
            );

            List<string> testStrings = new List<string> {
                "12 blerg",
                "1 apples",
                "  2 apples ignore_this",
                "3 oranges ignore_this",
                "this 5 6 should be ignored but fails 4 apples ignore_this"};

            foreach (var str in testStrings)
            {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str + " ----> " + amountOfThingsAnyWhere.ParseOrThrow(str));
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str + " exception: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple to do with Regex.

Comment: You did not mention you are using Pidgin, is this a hard requirement? As suggested by @jdweng, Regex can do the work, and string manipulation as well, though it can be harder to get right.

Comment: Thanks, yes it should be done via pidgin, the pidgin keyword is for some chat software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using Regular Expressions, here is how you can do it.
I am only showing for "apple"/"apples" but it would be similar for oranges, or any other word whose plural form requires suffixing with "s".

```cs
private List<string> CountApples(string s)
{
    Regex rg = new Regex(@"([0-9]+)\s\bapples?\b");
    MatchCollection matches = rg.Matches(s);

    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var quantifierGroup = match.Groups[1];
        result.Add(quantifierGroup.Value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Input:

```
"this 5 6 should be ignored but fails 4 apples ignore_this and 42 apples again"
```

Output:

```
[4, 42]
```

The regex `([0-9]+)\s\bapples?\b` is looking for any number `[0-9]+`, and putting this into a group `()`, to retrieve it later.
Then it expects a white space `\s` and either `apple` or `apples` exactly (thanks to the `\b` word delimiters.
It will not work for words starting with "apple" like "applewood".

Comment: Thanks but it was meant as a specific question for the pidgin parsing-combinator library :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and for editing your question. I suggest you put your Pidgin code in your question as well, not only in the dotnetfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the following:

```
Parser<char, string> amount = Digit.ManyString();
Parser<char, string> amountOfThings = 
    amount.Before(Whitespace.AtLeastOnce()).Before(multiThings);

Parser<char, string> amountOfThingsAnyWhere = 
    Any.SkipUntil(Try(Lookahead(amountOfThings))).Then(amountOfThings);
```

This works with your given input as well as:

```
"12 oranges",
"  12 oranges",
"xx12 oranges",
"  all text no digits ",
"2 apples ignore_this",
"xx2 apples ignore_this",
"xx2 2 apples ignore_this",
"apples",
"apples ignore_this"
```

- LookAhead is necessary to prevent SkipUntil from consuming the
  terminator (amountOfThings).
- Try is necessary to allow backpeddling when the start of the pattern
  is encountered (in this case any digit not followed by an apple or an
  orange).

I am still trying to get it to work when amountOfThings is modified to

```
Parser<char, string> amountOfThings =
    amount.Then(Whitespace.AtLeastOnce()).Then(multiThings);
```

I was hoping this would return '4 apples' and so on, but it only returns the name of the fruit alone!

EDIT:

Here is how to make it say the number and name of the fruit as well:

```
Parser<char, string> amount = Digit.ManyString();
Parser<char, string> amountOfThings = 
      amount
      .Then(Whitespace.AtLeastOnce())
      .Then(multiThings);

Parser<char, string> amountOfThingsEntire =
       amount
       .Before(Whitespace.AtLeastOnce())
       .Then(multiThings, (amountResult, fruitResult) => $"{amountResult} {fruitResult}");

Parser<char, string> amountOfThingsAnyWhere = 
    Any.SkipUntil(Try(Lookahead(amountOfThings))).Then(amountOfThingsEntire);
```